# hide headers of asp.net ajax control

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem: I would like to hide all of the headers of Asp.net ajax control from this link: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/tabs/tabs.aspx

Then I click next, then the tabContainer will select a next tab.

Is it possible?

thanks in advance.

Comment: You can always hide it using CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound more like you are in need of the Asp.Net Wizard Control